# How to listen to changes on ProviderContainer in Riverpod?

Tags: dart, dependency-injection, riverpod

In a context of pure Dart project I want to "watch" changes on dependencies. How do I listen to the changes?

As far as `read()` I am all fine i guess.

```
final container = ProviderContainer();
final dependency = container.read(myDependencyProvider);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend `ProviderObserver` and override `didUpdateProvider`

> ProviderObserver listens to the changes of a ProviderContainer.

[Here is the official explanation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/provider_observer)

Answer (score 2):

Actually per [Remi's answer on the issue in Github](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/425#issuecomment-950398024), the new, updated  recommended way to watch for changes outside of Flutter, is to use the `listen()` method on the `ProviderContainer` like so:

```dart
final provider = Provider((ref) => ...)

void main() {
  final container = ProviderContainer();

  container.listen(
    provider,
    (previous, value) => print('changed'),
  ); 
}
```

Comment: actually no its use ProviderObserver as the issue comment you reference is for Dart Apps only!

Comment: @FredGrott exactly why my answer says "outside of Flutter", ie Dart application.